# How to switch texts in Text Editor by script

Tags: python, text-editor

Cannot find proper `bpy.ops` command to switch texts in Text Editor(normally you do that from area header by clicking and selecting text block).

`bpy.context.space_data.text` <strike>is read only</strike>.

Is there a way?

Edit: the property is writable, my mistake, everything is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change it via [bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.text](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.html?highlight=texteditor#bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.text)

So if you run an operator from the text editor you can change it in the execute method like this:

```
def execute(self, context):
    context.space_data.text = bpy.data.texts['your_text']
```

Otherwise you have to find the text area in [screen.areas](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_1/bpy.types.Screen.html?highlight=screen.areas#bpy.types.Screen.areas) (given there is a text editor in the screen):

```
for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "TEXT_EDITOR":
        break
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Nothing found")

area.spaces[0].text = bpy.data.texts['your_text']
```

Comment: My statement that bpy.context.space_data.text is read-only is false, thanks. It was greyed out in outliner datablocks and that confused me, it makes sense its greyed out.